# oozie jobs that are signal free are started dealying

Tags: oozie

We have multiple jobs configured in oozie, and some jobs are signal free and some are dependent on signals. We have given signal free jobs start time 2AM and the jobs were starting firing during that time. From last one month we have noticed those signal free jobs started delaying by 1 hour. We are not sure why is it happening.

does any one have idea on this, why oozie jobs started executing with delay.

Comment: Can it be wrong daylight savings configuration?

Comment: Initially we had thought in the same way, but this problem started happening from last 45+ days and so. If we suspect the problem because of DST it should start occur in Nov/end of Sep. But we could see this problem from almost near to 2 months.

Comment: is the system time correct?

Comment: yes, system time is correct.